# host コマンドでIPアドレスの詳細を確認すると、「not found」になります

Tags: google-analytics, hosts

WAF（siteguard）で検出されたログから、IPアドレスの身元を知りたかったのですが、
下記のようなメッセージが返されます。

host xxx.xxx.xxx　←（IP）
in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

目的としては、ブロックされたものが、Google クローラーによるものなのかどうかを確認したかったのですが、

もし、このようなエラーがご存じの方がおられましたら、アドバイスをいただけますと助かります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そのアドレスに対して逆引きの設定がされていないということでしょう。

[Googleのクローラーは逆引きの結果が定義されている](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/verifying-googlebot?hl=ja)ので、少なくとも Google のクローラーではないと思われます。

Comment: int32_t様、こちら早急なご回答ありがとうございます！
大変助かりました。